# Difficulties in Understating for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I Don't Understand what should I do ? The Question is

Read from the user the number of cities (minimum 6 cities)

For each city: city name and the number of persons (minimum 10 persons) are entered.

For each person in a city: mass and height should be entered, BMI and BMI category have to be  computed and printed.

For each city, the number of persons and percent ratio in each BMI category should be computed and printed.

Finally, the program    should print a summary report with the following details:

- Number of    cities.
- Total number of persons and percent ratio of persons in    each BMI    category in all cities.
- The name of the best city which    has the maximum percent of persons in normal weight BMI category and    these people’s percent ratio.
- The name of the worst city which has    the maximum percent of persons in obese BMI category and these    people’s percent ratio.
- The name of the city which has the minimum    percent of persons in underweight BMI  category and these people’s    percentratio)

**What I tried to do :**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int NumberOfCity;
        System.out.printf("Enter number of Cities:  (Minimum of 6 cities required) ");
        NumberOfCity = input.nextInt();
        if (NumberOfCity < 6){
            System.out.print("Enter A number more than 6");
        } else {
            System.out.printf("Number of cities are " + NumberOfCity);
        }
        while (NumberOfCity >0){
            String city; int NumberOfPerson;
            System.out.printf("Enter The Name of the city");
            city = input.next();
            System.out.printf("Enter The number of persons for the city  (Minimum of 10 Persons Required)");
            NumberOfPerson = input.nextInt();
            if (NumberOfPerson < 10){
                System.out.printf("Enter A Number more than 10");
            } else {
                while (NumberOfPerson > 0){
                    int mass , height ;
                    System.out.printf("Enter The mass of the person");
                    mass = input.nextInt();
                    System.out.printf("Enter The Height of the person");
                    height = input.nextInt();
                    double BMI = mass / Math.pow(height,2);
                    if (BMI < 18.5){
                        System.out.printf("The person BMI is UnderWeight");
                        int x = 0;
                        x +=1;
                    } if (BMI ==18.5 && BMI <25){
                        System.out.printf("The person BMI is Normal");
                        int y = 0;
                        y +=1;
                    } if (BMI ==25 && BMI <30){
                        System.out.printf("The person BMI is Overweight");
                        int z = 0;
                        z +=1;

                    } else {
                        System.out.printf("The person BMI is Obese");
                        int a =0;
                                a+=1;
                    }
                }
            }
            NumberOfCity--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What part are you stuck on?

Comment: This about what `BMI ==18.5 && BMI <25` actually checks.

Comment: You never decrement `NumberOfPerson`, this causes an infinite loop.

Comment: I don't know how to store the name and the number of the persons of each city individually so i can call them

Comment: Also i can't store the values globally so i can call them later or modify them

Comment: *I don't know how to store the name and the number of the persons of each city individually so i can call them* Then your missing some crucial aspects of Java.  The instructor should have talked about arrays and/or Lists.

Comment: Try storing the data for each city in a new class (e.g. a class named `City`, with fields `String name` and `List<Person> persons`).

Answer (score 0):

Without regard to some obvious problems (as mentioned in the comments) you should not try to do this all at once.

- Break up the problem into small steps.  Start with reading in the values and printing them just to make certain that works.
- For other parts, temporarily comment out the console input section that should now be working and assign canned input to fields and arrays as needed.  This will make your task much easier and go faster.  You can revert back to the console input when the other aspects of the program have been tested and working.
- Then give it a final test with the taking input from the console again.  Do any final cleanup and documentation.

If you have problems with something not working, that is what SO is for.  If you have problems understanding parts of the assignment, you should discuss that with your instructor.

Comment: Thank you , but the problem is am not allowed to use arrays or objects yet , because it's not covered in the course sir .
but you pointed a good way to think about how to solve it .

Comment: You're going to use objects whether you've learned about them or not.  String's are objects.

Comment: @WJS: FYI, a [possible help vampire](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67851676/522444)